# How to disabled/override error dialog if simcard is not installed in phone

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to override default android error dialog which is showing when simcard is not installed on phone and if we try to make a outgoing call.
Basically from my app if someone try to do outgoing call from phone and if simcard is not installed then i want to make a call using sip service. But problem is that some time a default error dialog appear and show a message that No SIM Card Installed. Here is my code:

```
  <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallHandler">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

in android:

```
  @Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");

        if (!isSimCardInstalled() && isSipServiceRunning())  {
            ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(SipService.OUTGOING_CALL).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, checkCallingCode(phoneNumber)));
        }
    }
```

to check simcard:

```
 public boolean isSimCardInstalled() {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm.getSimState() != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT ? true : false;
}
```

Sometime it works properly and sometime phone display a internal phone error message. How i can disabled this default error message dialog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the broadcast `Intent` from being processed by downstream apps (like the standard Android dialer). To do this, clear the result data in `onReceive()`, like this:

```
    if (!isSimCardInstalled() && isSipServiceRunning())  {
        ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(SipService.OUTGOING_CALL).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, checkCallingCode(phoneNumber)));
        setResultData(null);
    }
```